# Plot each number array element as a horizontal line

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an easy way to plot each array element as a horizontal line in python?

Example:

```
some_array = [2 4 5 8 4 3 ... n]
```

Now I want a graph that plots the horizontal lines:

```
y_1 = 2
y_2 = 4
y_3 = 5
.
.
.
y_n = n
```

The length of some_array is not fixed, as in I don't know how many elements it will contain, so the code has to be able to handle this.

I know I can do this with :

```
plt.plot((x[0], x[-1]), (some_array[0], some_array[0]), 'k-')
```

and maybe put it in a while loop so it runs the length of the array, but I feel like there is a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `plt.hlines`:

```
some_array = [2, 4, 5, 8, 4, 3]
plt.hlines(some_array, 0, 1, colors=['b', 'g', 'r', 'y', 'c', 'm'])
plt.ylim(1, 9)
```

[image: hlines.png]

Comment: Is there a way to make them all different colors and/or styles?

Comment: @renegade Of course, just look at the docstring. http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=vlines#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines

Comment: @renegade You don't *get* the colors, you pass the colors you want.as an argument. I added colors and some vertical padding so all non-overlapping lines are visible.

Comment: but now when I plot a legend, the colors don't seem to associate with each line... hmmm

Comment: @renegade Yes, if you want to label each line you need to plot one by one (or use tricks like proxy artists which aren't going to make your life any easier anyway). I think this is a design decision, 'vlines()` and `hlines()` are like a `bar()` and `barh()`, you can't label each bar in a bar plot either.